# I can not save data to Shareprefence String

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have a problem with saving string to SharedPreference. This class save number Card and get String from SharedPreference.
this my class MyShrePreference. I don't know why that string is not saving to SharedPreference.

```
public class MySharepreference {

    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "POSITION";
    public static final String POSITION = "current";
    public String nameString;

    public MySharepreference() {
        super();
    }


    public void saveNumberCard(Context context, String position) {
        SharedPreferences settings;
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        editor = settings.edit();
        editor.putString(POSITION, position);
        editor.commit();
    }

    public String getNumberCard(Context context) {
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
        sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        if (sharedPreferences.contains(POSITION)) {
            nameString = sharedPreferences.getString(POSITION, "");
        }
        return nameString;
    }

}
```

save to SharedPreference to the adapter

onBindViewHolder

```
 @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(CardViewHolder holder, final int position) {

  mySharepreference = new MySharepreference();

        if (position == lastCheckedPos) {
            mySharepreference.saveNumberCard(mContext, card.getNumberCard());
}
```

Comment: explain better your problem.

Comment: Can you add the code where you call this method

Comment: Your code is fine, Just remove **if (sharedPreferences.contains(POSITION))**

Comment: how did you declare your `mContext` in bholderclass? I mean, are you sure that you are passing the `mContext` properly?

Comment: I save data to Sharepreference  in adapter

Comment: @EwelinaMaj what do you mean?

Comment: @MohammadJulfikar I have RecycleView to save data onBindViewHolder

Answer (score 0):

```
public class SharedPreferenceUtils {
    private static final Context context = MyApplication.getInstance();
    private static String SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME = "myapplicationpref";
    private static SharedPreferences preference;

    public static SharedPreferences getSharedPrefrence() {
        if (preference == null) {
            preference = context.getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREFERENCES_FILE_NAME,
                    Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        }
        return preference;

    }


    public static String getStringValueFromSharedPrefarence(String key, String defaultValue) {
        return getSharedPrefrence().getString(key, defaultValue);

    }
    public static boolean getBooleanValueFromSharedPrefarence(String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return getSharedPrefrence().getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static boolean setBooleanValueToSharedPrefarence(String key, boolean value) {
        return getSharedPrefrence().edit().putBoolean(key, value).commit();

    }
    public static boolean setStringValueToSharedPrefarence(String key, String value) {
        return getSharedPrefrence().edit().putString(key, value).commit();

    }
    public static boolean setStringSetToSharedPrefarence(String key, Set<String> value) {
        return getSharedPrefrence().edit().putStringSet(key, value).commit();

    }

}
```

Comment: rest of your code is good, this line is leaking context private static final Context context = MyApplication.getInstance(); , instead you can use singleton design pattern and pass application context to it.

Answer (score 0):

change the code mContext to getApplicationContext(), like

```
     mySharepreference.saveNumberCard(getApplicationContext(), card.getNumberCard());
```